# Migration from HSQL to OrientDB

Tags: hsqldb, database-migration, orientdb

I am looking into ways to migrate from `Hyper SQL DB` to `OrientDB`. Looking for suggestions on any tool/utility available for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Teleporter,because Teleporter is fully compatible with several RDBMS that have a JDBC drivers: Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, PostgreSQL and HyperSQL. Teleporter manages all the necessary type conversions between the different DBMSs and imports all your data as a Graph in OrientDB.

More info at this [link](http://orientdb.com/orientdb-teleporter-making-migrations-easier-part-2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @lsavio. Will try this out.